# Should I define methods as static in class library to use in Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

*Scenario*: I have a console application which references couple of class libraries. *ClassLibEmployee* pulls the data from SQL database and returns a List. I need to loop through the list of Employee's and send that to a WebAPI and update SQL DB with status. I created *ClassLibPay* which a wrapper for WebAPI.

```
ClassLibEmployee.EmployeeData ed = new ClassLibEmployee.EmployeeData();
var elist = ed.PullEmployees();

foreach (Employee e in elist) {

    bool stat = ClassLibPay.ServiceWrap.Sendtopay(e.Id, e.Name, e.Pay, e.ExemptFlag, e.Hours);

    ed.ChageStatus(e.Id, e.Name, e.Pay, e.ExemptFlag, e.Hours, stat);
}
```

- In ClassLibEmployee, I defined class as `public class EmployeeData`
- In ClassLibPay, I defined class as `public static class ServiceWrap`

**Questions:**

1. since I will be calling ChangeStatus method in EmployeeData for each employee, should that be a static class?
2. ServiceWrap is calling a service, is there a way to avoid creating instance of the service, for every Sendtopay call?

---

**Console App**
    --*References ClassLibEmployee*

```
public class EmployeeData
{
    public List<Employee> PullEmployees()
    {
    }
}
```

**ConsoleApp**
    --References ClassLibPay
        -- ClassLibPay calls a WebAPI

```
public static class ServiceWrap
{
    public static bool Sendtopay(int id, string name, decimal pay, bool flg, int hours)
    {
        using (EDataSvc service = new EDataSvc())
        {
            service.serviceMethod(id,name,pay,flg,hours);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for Dependency Injection. We tend not to like static classes unless they are truly stateless and trivial helpers, even then we tend to use DI as it makes everything easily testable. I would suggest starting to move down this path

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thanks. Is there a simple example you can point me to?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent creating every time class, you definitely should move to DI way as Michael said.

This is very simple example how to use DI with console application based on [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac) library. Below we have Main console application and two classes where one is our wrapper(where maybe you want to prepare your data, and eDataService which should just send data to back-end. We register both classes as PerLifeTimeScope(here, this is singleton's - in another words have only one instance if we get it from the DI container). Of course you can choose ready frameworks with already integrated DI containers.

```
class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<EDataSvc>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            var container = builder.Build();

            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var service = scope.Resolve<MyService>();
                service.MakeRequestAsync("test");
            }
        }
    }

    public class EDataSvc
    {
        public void SendRequestAsync()
        {
            //TODO:Send request
        }
    }

    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private EDataSvc _eDataService;

        public void MakeRequestAsync(EDataSvc eDataSvc)
        {
            _eDataService = eDataSvc;
        }

        public void MakeRequestAsync(string parameter)
        {
            //TODO prepare your data or additional logic

            _eDataService.SendRequestAsync();
        }
    }

    public interface IMyService
    {
        void MakeRequestAsync(string parameter);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Yauhen. I will try this one.